# Groovy or Java equivalent of sumproduct?

Tags: groovy

Before I writing my own, does anyone know if Groovy or Java has something pre-built which is similar to Excel's sumproduct function?

The quasi syntax for sumproduct is something like

```
def list1 = [2,3,4]
def list2 = [5,10,20]

SUMPRODUCT(list1, list2 ...) = 120
```

You will get 120 ((2*5) + (3*10) + (4*20) = 120)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can `transpose()`, `collect()` and `sum` the result:

```
def list1 = [2,3,4]
def list2 = [5,10,20]

assert [list1, list2]
    .transpose()
    .collect { it[0] * it[1] }
    .sum()  == 120
```

Answer (score 3):

not really the out-of-box SUMPRODUCT substitute, but still an one-liner:

```
def list1 = [2,3,4]
def list2 = [5,10,20]

assert 120 == GroovyCollections.transpose( list1, list2 ).sum{ it[ 0 ] * it[ 1 ] }
```

Comment: You shouldn't call `GroovyCollections.transpose` directly. That's an extension method added to collections

Comment: @tim_yates, doesn't `[ list1, list2 ]` instantiate 1 extra list comparing to `GroovyCollections.transpose()`?

Answer (score 2):

Here's a version of sumproduct that isn't limited to two input lists:

```
def sumproduct(List... lists) {
  (lists as List).transpose().sum { it.inject(1) { prod, val -> prod * val } }
}
```

Calling it with `sumproduct([2,3,4], [5,10,20], [1,2,3])` returns 310.